# Lost reference after method execution

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I followed this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kQqqo_9FfsU&t=243s) on how to create health bars automatically for units.
This is my `HealthBar` class.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
    
public class HealthBar : MonoBehaviour
{
    #region SerializeFields
    
    [SerializeField] private Image foregroundImage;
    [SerializeField] private float updateSpeedInSec = 0.5f;
    [SerializeField] private float positionOffset = 1f;
    
    #endregion
    
    #region NonSerializeFields
    
    private Health health;
    
    #endregion
    
    public void SetHealth(Health healthToSet)
    {
            health = healthToSet;
            healthToSet.OnHealthPctChanged += HandleHealthChanged;
    }
    
    private void HandleHealthChanged(float pct)
    {
            StartCoroutine(ChangeToPct(pct));
    }
    
    private IEnumerator ChangeToPct(float pct)
    {
            float preChangedPct = foregroundImage.fillAmount;
            float elapsedTime = 0f;
    
            while (elapsedTime < updateSpeedInSec)
            {
                elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
                foregroundImage.fillAmount = Mathf.Lerp(preChangedPct, pct, elapsedTime / updateSpeedInSec);
                yield return null;
            }
    
            foregroundImage.fillAmount = pct;
    }
    
    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        var worldToScreenPoint = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(health.transform.position + (Vector3) Vector2.up * positionOffset);
        transform.position = worldToScreenPoint;
    }
    
    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        health.OnHealthPctChanged -= HandleHealthChanged;
    }
}
```

So this is my HealthBarController class, which is where the `SetHealth` method is called, put on a canvas.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
 
public class HealthBarController : MonoBehaviour
{
    #region SerializeFields
 
    [SerializeField] private HealthBar healthBar;
 
    #endregion
 
    #region NonSerializeFields
 
    private Dictionary<Health, HealthBar> healthBars = new Dictionary<Health, HealthBar>();
 
    #endregion
 
    private void Awake()
    {
        Health.OnHealthAdded += AddHealthBar;
        Health.OnHealthRemoved += RemoveHealthBar;
    }
 
    private void AddHealthBar(Health health)
    {
        if (healthBars.ContainsKey(health)) return;
 
        var newHealthBar = Instantiate(healthBar, transform);
        healthBars.Add(health, newHealthBar);
        healthBar.SetHealth(health);
    }
 
    private void RemoveHealthBar(Health health)
    {
        if (!healthBars.ContainsKey(health)) return;
 
        Destroy(healthBars[health].gameObject);
        healthBars.Remove(health);
    }
}
```

And this is my Health class on a player character.

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
 
public class Health : MonoBehaviour, IDamageable
{
    #region SerializeFields
 
    [SerializeField] protected int maxHealth = 100;
 
    public static event Action<Health> OnHealthAdded = delegate {  };
    public static event Action<Health> OnHealthRemoved = delegate {  };
    public event Action<float> OnHealthPctChanged = delegate {  };
 
    #endregion
 
    #region NonSerializeFields
 
    protected int currentHealth;
 
    #endregion
 
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        currentHealth = maxHealth;
        OnHealthAdded(this);
    }
 
    public void TakeDamage(int damage)
    {
        currentHealth -= damage;
        float currentHealthPct = (float) currentHealth / maxHealth;
        OnHealthPctChanged(currentHealthPct);
     
        if (currentHealth <= 0)
        {
            Die();
        }
    }
 
    protected void Die()
    {
        OnHealthRemoved(this);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is in the `LateUpdate` method, the `health` field is null, even though in the `SetHealth` method, it was set properly.

Comment: The code you provided works unmodified as long as SetHealth is called with a valid Health input prior to the first LateUpdate(), how and when are you calling the SetHealth method?

Comment: I've edited my post with the classes that call the `SetHealth` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `AddHealthBar` method of your **HealthBarController.cs** script you are assigning the `Health` class of your character to the Prefab `healthBar` rather than the newly created `Health` instance `newHealthBar`.

Simply replace `healthBar.SetHealth(health);` with `newHealthBar.SetHealth(health);` (line 30).

Comment: OMG thank you soooo much! I've been struggling with that dumb mistake for couple days lol.